# Should I have flagged the spammy answer as well as the bad question?

Tags: discussion

When reviewing first posts yesterday I came upon an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899130/desktop-appstore-for-linux-windows-and-mac) that I thought was pretty spammy - it was essentially just a link to their own website.  I considered flagging it as spam, but then figured that instead I should flag the question (which was just asking for links to app stores, and would seem to invite these sort of spammy answers).  I happened to check my flags to see if it had been marked helpful, and it hadn't yet.  I clicked on the link to see if it had been edited/improved, but all I saw was that that spammy answer is now gone.  This leads me to assume that someone else did flag it as spam and it was removed.

Should I have flagged both the question and answer, or was it alright that I just flagged the question?

Here is the post in question:

[image: deleted post]

Comment: Flagging the question will not show the answer in the review queue. In this example you've provided, a reviewer would only see the bad question. Someone would have to flag the spam separately for it to be seen. So if multiple things need to be flagged, especially in the case of a spam account, it helps keep the place tidy.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Absolutely, flag it as spam. Also, flag the question for closure (or VTC if you are 3K+).

Unlike link-only answers, where you shouldn't flag NAA on a link-question, spam flags notify moderators of potential spam accounts, deliver a very harsh penalty to the posting user, and train our spam filter.

If you see something that is obviously spam; **flag it**.

As for that answer, it was deleted, but not marked as spam (it sure looks like spam to me).

**Update** It has now been marked as spam and deleted as such.

Answer (score 9):

Answers on closed questions are not immune to review.  If you see anything wrong with an answer, deal with it appropriately.

You should be especially vigilant when it comes to spam/offensive answers on closed questions.  Since the question is closed, it's not likely to be noticed anymore by most users who police the questions/answers and be flagged and deleted.  If *you* saw the problem and is legitimate, then don't feel like you shouldn't just because the question is closed.  Just because the question is closed, the answer still exists which is a bigger problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes sense.  However I wasn't asking what to do with a closed question (the question was open when I reviewed the answer). I was asking if the general rule "flag the question, not all the answers" held if the answers were spam